# Local email folder does not load in Thunderbird after copying from another computer

Tags: thunderbird

I copied my "Local Folders" mail folder from another computer and after setting up my email account in Thunderbird, I pasted my old "Local Folders" here, and the mail folders appeared correctly in Thunderbird. However, although my folder structure appears to be copied, Thunderbird does not actually load my e-mails. I can click the folder, and it shows the "Loading" mouse cursor, but nothing happens. Also, it shows a tiny yellow box below the cursor, whenever I move over one of those folders. This does not happen when I move over a working IMAP folder. Any idea what this could be? Here's an image:

[image]

Using Arch Linux, Thunderbird 7.0.1

Comment: This is a hard question to answer, because there are many different IMAP servers, mailbox layouts, and possible causes.  Please tell us what IMAP server you're using, and show us a long listing (`ls -l`) of  the root mail folder and one of the subfolders (10 lines or so anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I once had problems with a mailbox which I wasn't able to move between two windows boxes, I guess there were some glitches in the profile. I could solve the problem using some [import-/export-addon](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Turns out, it was related to the permissions of the folders. My user did not have write permissions (only read), and after fixing this they open again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Make a directory thunderbird and install thunderbird into that folder. Make a directory called `email1` and put your emails into this folder. Go into thunderbird and rightclick on local folders go to settings Then browse for the `email1` folder and click ok

Your emails will show in local folders and you will be able to drag and drop emails to the folder or new folders as you please.